# How find this sum $\sum_{ab+cd=2^m}ac=?$

Tags: number-theory, summation

Find this sum (where $m$ is a fixed positive integer)
$$\sum_{\substack{ab+cd=2^m\\ a,b,c,d \text{ are odd}}}ac.$$

My idea: since $$ab+cd=2^m\Longrightarrow ab=2^m-cd$$
and $a,b,c,d$ is odd numbers,then
$$a=2a_{1}+1,b=2b_{1}+1,c=2c_{1}+1,d=2d_{1}+1$$
then I can't works,Thank you very  much

Comment: Do you want a solution in terms of $m$? If you set $a = 1, c = 1$ then there are an infinitely many $b, d$ such that $b+d = 2^m$ if $m$ is not fixed, so the sum diverges.

Comment: I don't understand your question. What does that summation means?

Comment: @user92774,Thank you, you are right,$m$ is fixed.Thank you

Comment: Do you want the sum to run over positive/nonnegative integers? I suppose you do. As in my edit, formatting info under a summation sign can be done with \substack{info \\ more info \\ even more info...}

Comment: @barto,yes,that's mean.

Comment: I wonder if this bounty will be awarded or just automatically half-awarded, as usual with @chinamath.

Comment: @chinamath: When you offer a bounty, you should award it when there is a solution provided, or at least respond to indicate what you think is lacking in the reply.

Answer (score 13):

A simple idea is to fix both $a$ and $c$, then count the number of solution of $ab+cd=2^m$ with $b$ and $d$ both odd. If $a$ and $c$ are not coprime there is clearly no solution; in general, the number of solutions is given by the coefficient of $x^{2^m}$ in:
$$(x^a+x^{3a}+x^{5a}+\ldots)\cdot(x^c+x^{3c}+x^{5c}+\ldots)=\frac{x^{a+c}}{(1-x^{2a})(1-x^{2c})},$$
so your initial sum is just:
$$ S = [x^{2^m}]\sum_{a,c\text{ odd}}\frac{ax^a}{1-x^{2a}}\cdot \frac{cx^c}{1-x^{2c}}=[x^{2^m}]\left(\sum_{a\text{ odd}}\frac{ax^a}{1-x^{2a}}\right)^2,\tag{1}$$
or:
$$S = [x^{2^m}]\left(\sum_{n\text{ odd}}\sigma(n)\,x^n\right)^2,\tag{2}$$
where $\sigma(n)$ is just the sum of the divisors of $n$, that is a multiplicative function. $(2)$ gives:
$$ S = \sum_{n\text{ odd},\,n<2^m}\sigma(n)\cdot\sigma(2^m-n) = \sum_{n\text{ odd},\,n<2^m}\sigma(n2^m-n^2).\tag{3}$$
I do not know if $(3)$ can be further simplified, but since $\sigma(n)\geq n+1$, we have:
$$ S \geq \frac{1}{12}\cdot 2^{3m}+\frac{1}{6}\cdot 2^m,$$
with the correct magnitude being probably a bit bigger. By applying the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality to $(3)$, since the average order of $\sigma(n)^2$ is known, we can have an upper bound, too.

---

**Update:** The Han De Brujin conjecture

> $$ S = 2^{3m-3}$$

probably follows from the Eisenstein-series identity:
$$\sigma_3(n) = \frac{1}{5}\left\{6n\sigma(n)-\sigma(n) + 12\sum_{0<k<n}\sigma(k)\sigma(n-k)\right\}.$$
than can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_function#Divisor_sum_convolutions) or from the Ramanujan identity stated in the fourth-to-last line in [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein_series).

> In facts, the identity $(1.14)$ and the Theorems $(4.1)$ and $(4.2)$
>   in [this](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.180.7778&rep=rep1&type=pdf) paper of Hahn set the conjecture **true**. A simpler
>   account is also given [here](http://math.nie.edu.sg/pctoh/archive/EisensteinLevel2_revised.pdf) by Pee Choon Toh through the identity
>   $(1.13b)$ with $j=4$.

---

Now I wonder about the existence of a more elementary proof of the Han De Brujin conjecture, maybe through the Lagrange identity
$$ (a^2+d^2)(b^2+c^2) = (ab+cd)^2+(ac-bd)^2.$$

Comment: Just to confirm: $S_m=8^{m-1}$, for a given $m$, follows from the Eisenstein-series identity. The sum over $k$ in the Eisenstein-series identity for $k=2^r\cdot j$ summed for odd $j$ gives $\sigma(2^r)^2\cdot S_{m-r}$, where $S_m$ is given by (3). Induction on $m$ then confirms the result for a given $S_m$.

Answer (score 10):

*Disclaimer:* this is only a partial answer,
but something may be better than nothing.
The approach is a **brute force** method, programming is in Pascal:

```
program china_math;

function twee(macht : integer) : integer;
{
  Compute 2^macht
}
var
  k : integer;
  h : integer;
begin
  h := 1;
  for k := 1 to macht do
    h := h shl 1;
  twee := h;
end;

procedure test(m : integer; blah : boolean);
{
  The problem
}
var
  i,j,k,a,b,c,d : integer;
  s,N,ii,jj,kk : integer;
  OK : boolean;
begin
  N := twee(m);
  s := 0;
  ii := (N div 2);
  for i := 1 to ii do
  begin 
    a := 2*i-1;
    jj := ((N div a) div 2)+1;
    for j := 1 to jj do
    begin 
      b := 2*j-1;
      kk := ((N-a*b) div 2)+1;
      if (N-a*b) > 0 then
      for k := 1 to kk do
      begin 
        c := 2*k-1;
        OK := (N-a*b) mod c = 0;
        if not OK then Continue;
        d := (N-a*b) div c;
        if blah then Writeln(a,'',b,'+',c,'',d,'=',N);
        s := s + a*c;
      end;
    end;
  end;
  if not blah then
  Writeln(m:6,s:12,' =?= ',twee(3*m-3));
end;

procedure doen;
var
  m : integer;
begin
  test(4,true);
  Writeln;
  for m := 1 to 11 do
  test(m,false);
end;

begin
  doen;
end.
```

Computational details for e.g. $m=4$:

```
a*b+c*d=2^m
1*1+1*15=16
1*1+3*5=16
1*1+5*3=16
1*1+15*1=16
1*3+1*13=16
1*3+13*1=16
1*5+1*11=16
1*5+11*1=16
1*7+1*9=16
1*7+3*3=16
1*7+9*1=16
1*9+1*7=16
1*9+7*1=16
1*11+1*5=16
1*11+5*1=16
1*13+1*3=16
1*13+3*1=16
1*15+1*1=16
3*1+1*13=16
3*1+13*1=16
3*3+1*7=16
3*3+7*1=16
3*5+1*1=16
5*1+1*11=16
5*1+11*1=16
5*3+1*1=16
7*1+1*9=16
7*1+3*3=16
7*1+9*1=16
9*1+1*7=16
9*1+7*1=16
11*1+1*5=16
11*1+5*1=16
13*1+1*3=16
13*1+3*1=16
15*1+1*1=16
```

Output for $1 \le m \le 11$:

```
     m         sum =?= 2^(3*m-3)
     1           1 =?= 1
     2           8 =?= 8
     3          64 =?= 64
     4         512 =?= 512
     5        4096 =?= 4096
     6       32768 =?= 32768
     7      262144 =?= 262144
     8     2097152 =?= 2097152
     9    16777216 =?= 16777216
    10   134217728 =?= 134217728
    11  1073741824 =?= 1073741824
```

This leads to the following **Conjecture:**
$$\sum_{\substack{ab+cd=2^m\\ a,b,c,d \text{ are odd}}}ac \,=\, 2^{\,3m-3}$$
And the numerical work shows that the Conjecture is a Theorem for $1 \le m \le 11$ ;
which is as far as we can go with the given limited precision of standard (Delphi) Pascal.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$\ds{{\cal J}\pars{N} \equiv \sum_{\substack{ab +cd = 2^{m}\\[1mm] a,b,c,d\ \mbox{are odd}}}ac:\ {\Large ?}.\qquad\mbox{where}\ {\large N = 2^{m}}}$

> \begin{align}
> {\cal J}\pars{N}&=\sum_{\ell = 0}^{\infty}\pars{2\ell + 1}
> \sum_{\ell' = 0}^{\infty}\pars{2\ell' + 1}
> \delta_{\pars{2\ell + 1}b + \pars{2\ell' + 1}d,N}
> \\[3mm]&=\sum_{\ell = 0}^{\infty}\sum_{\ell' = 0}^{\infty}
> \pars{2\ell + 1}\pars{2\ell' + 1}
> \int_{\verts{z} = 1}{1 \over
> z^{-\pars{2\ell + 1}b -\pars{2\ell' + 1}d + N + 1}}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
> \\[3mm]&=\int_{\verts{z} = 1}
> {{\cal F}\pars{z,b}{\cal F}\pars{z,d} \over z^{N + 1}}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
> \quad\mbox{where}\quad{\cal F}\pars{z,\mu}\equiv
> \sum_{\ell = 0}^{\infty}\pars{2\ell + 1}z^{\pars{2\ell + 1}\mu}\tag{1}
> \end{align}

Let's evaluate ${\cal F}\pars{z,\mu}$:
\begin{align}
{\cal F}\pars{z,\mu}&=
{z \over \mu}\,\totald{}{z}\sum_{\ell = 0}^{\infty}z^{\pars{2\ell + 1}\mu}
=
{z \over \mu}\,\totald{}{z}\pars{z^{\mu} \over 1 - z^{2\mu}}
=-\,{z \over \mu}\,\totald{}{z}\pars{{1 \over z^{\mu} - z^{-\mu}}}
\\[3mm]&={z \over \mu}\,
{\mu z^{\mu - 1} - \pars{-\mu}z^{-\mu - 1} \over \pars{z^{\mu} - z^{-\mu}}^{2}}
=
{z^{\mu} + z^{-\mu} \over \pars{z^{\mu} - z^{-\mu}}^{2}}\,,\quad
\mbox{Notice that}\
{\cal F}\pars{\expo{\ic\theta},\mu}=-\,\half\,{\cos\pars{\mu\theta} \over \sin^{2}\pars{\mu\theta}}
\end{align}

> $$
> {\cal J}\pars{N}
> =
> {1 \over \pars{N - 1}!}\,\lim_{z \to 0}\,\partiald[N - 1]{}{z}
> \bracks{{z^{b} + z^{-b} \over \pars{z^{b} - z^{-b}}^{2}}\,
>         {z^{d} + z^{-d} \over \pars{z^{d} - z^{-d}}^{2}}}\,,\qquad
> N = 2^{m}
> $$

Can you evaluate the derivatives and take the limit ?.

Comment: If you can answer the last question yourself, please do it!

Comment: I just see a re-formulation of my $(1)$, is there something more?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio It's true. I like the systematic way. I'm very bad when I try to guess. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is mainly a comment related to the answers of Han de Bruijn and Jack D'Aurizio, but it may be of interest.

Generalizing the OP's problem to ask for

$$\sum_{\substack{ab+cd=2N\\ a,b,c,d \text{ are odd}}}ac$$

and computing the cases $2N=6$, $10$, and $12$ (to complement Han de Bruijn's computations for $2N=2$, $4$, and $8$), I get the first six terms of [A007331](https://oeis.org/A007331), which are coefficients of a modular form.

Comment: The connection with Eisenstein series is now completely disclosed :)